Three tags for Transaction Malleability
We currently have at least three tags for transaction malleability:
txid-malleability, malleability, transaction-malleability.

They should be merged into one tag. My suggestion would be transaction-malleability as, while it may be the transaction id that is changed, I haven't seen it called transaction id malleability so far.
Update:

txid-malleability, malleability have been merged into transaction-malleability. 
txid-malleability has been added as synonym for transaction-malleability

